# Is there a way to make a SQL query that returns as much data as possible on a given time?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I'm creating a script that fetches large amounts of data from an i Series/AS400 server (DB2) and then send it to kafka topics. But the query is taking too much time (2 to 3m) to return the results and sometimes I get timeouts errors.

So, I was wondering if is there a way to make a SQL query that returns as much data as possible on a given time and preventing me from getting SQL errors like a timeout?

For example:

```
SELECT id, user, email 
FROM users 
DURING 10s;
```

and it will select as much users as possible in 10 seconds and then stop, and return the results? So I can keep fetching data synchronously and send to Kafka?

Comment: Short answer: "No." Longer answer: What RDBMS are you using and what problem are you trying to solve by doing this? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/438222).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You cannot specify the time in the query. What if you need 9 seconds to establish the connection? In case you want as many rows in 10 seconds and stop, then that is something you can implement in your client code

Comment: You cannot do what you want. What are you trying to do? More details required.

How many rows in the table, is the table static or being continually written to? I guess id is unique?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement pagination with small page sizes (1k-10k rows?). For ideal results, your query should need to meet three conditions:

1. The query needs to be pipeline-able.
2. The query should include an `ORDER BY` clause.
3. The `ORDER BY` clause should use a UNIQUE key, to implement *key-set pagination*.

Now, condition #2 and #3 are necessary for correct results (no missing/duplicate rows between pages). Condition #1 is highly desirable, but not strictly necessary; if your query doesn't meet it, then each pagination call will be expensive, and could potentially time out.